# Xcode can't handle key encryption Ed25519

Tags: xcode, github, ssh, ecdsa

More than a question this is a sharing information post.

If you pull private repos via SSH, you should create an `id_ecdsa` because Xcode does not accept Ed25519 key, instead since github does not accept RSA-SHA1 anymore since yesterday.

https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

To generate it use: `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C "your_email@example.com"`

You can follow the next steps of config from here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: Xcode 13.3 added support for ed25519 keys https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes

Answer (score 8):

These are end to end steps for fixing this problem:

Steps:

1. `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C "your_email@example.com"` (Same as what OP said)
2. `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub`
3. Go to Github -> Login -> Settings -> SSH & GPG Keys -> type "Xcode" for the title and command paste the RSA key
4. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Sign into the github account if not already.
5. Select SSH for "Clone using"
6. For SSH Key select `id_ecdsa`. Make sure you select the private key, not the public.

Comment: You need `Xcode 13.3` and above because that version supports ecdsa.

Comment: @skymook correct, not every company is ready to upgrade to 13.3 so these are the steps for below 13.3